# Deploying a WPF application using ClickOnce and Team Build

Tags: wpf, build, clickonce

I have a WPF application that builds fine, I can even publish it (localhost) using ClickOnce - no problem.

I want to create a Team build that will update the ClickOnce site, but can't find anyone that has done this or knows how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use this code here to get what I wanted out of this:
http://www.imaginaryrealities.com/post/2009/03/29/Updating-a-ClickOnce-manifest-using-MSBuild.aspx

This was a little too much for me (we aren't signing our manifests, for example), but it'll definitely get you most of the way there.

The only thing missing is copying the files to your webserver once they are all packaged, but if you know anything about MSBuild, you ought to be fine there.

Also, be sure and use "MSBuild" when doing searches for this kind of thing... "Team Build" will generally only get you marketing material.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Anderson.  I'm curious, if you aren't signing your manifest aren't you running into trust issues?

Comment: Nah, it's an internal app.  They removed that requirement for clients that are running .NET 3.5 SP1.  Things got a lot easier when we didn't have to sign anymore :)